# Could a iOS app received Notifiction from another project with Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have builded a iOS app via firebase project (named: A project).Then my

iOS app could received notification with A proeject.

Could any solutions let my iOS app received notification form firebase

project (named: B project)？

---

my iOS app with A project could read/write realtime database with B project

via setting 「FirebaseOptions」.

so any others could help me that how to received notification from B 
project?

---

my code as below:

```html
// [END register_for_notifications],Default configuration with A project
FirebaseApp.configure() 
// Load a named file. another configuration with B project 
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-coinExchange2", ofType: "plist")
guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
 else { return false }
FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
```

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

I only choose one configuration at runtime. How to contain dual configuration at runtime?(Because FirebaseApp.configure only can be initialed once time.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Firebase supports accessing multiple projects in a single application. You can check the [official blog post here for Android, iOS and web](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) and the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/) (including iOS).

Here's the excerpt from the docs -

> ### **Support multiple environments in your iOS application**
>
> By default,
>   `FirebaseApp.configure()` will load the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file
>   bundled with the application. If your development and production
>   environments are configured as separate targets in XCode, you can:
>
> Download both `GoogleService-Info.plist` files Store the two files in
>   different directories Add both to your XCode project Associate the
>   different files with the different targets using the Target Membership
>   panel: Target Membership panel
>
> If the builds are part of a single target, the best option is to give
>   both configuration files unique names (e.g.
>   GoogleService-Info-Free.plist and GoogleService-Info-Paid.plist). Then
>   choose at runtime which plist to load. This is shown in the following
>   example:
>
> ```
> // Load a named file.
> let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyGoogleService", ofType: "plist")
> guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
>   else { assert(false, "Couldn't load config file") }
> FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
> ```

Comment: noob, Thanks your reply. I followed above steps, my iOS app still can't received notification from B project. My iOS app only received from A project. official documentation didn't explain about "Notification" with multiple  environments

Comment: did any one help me how to solve my problem? one target ios app received notification from two project with firebase?                                               one ios app only FirebaseApp.configure() once time?

Comment: @HunterChen This dual configuration is working for me on both Android and Web. I didn't get the chance to check it on iOS yet. Can you create a sample application without any other code in it except the configuration and see if it's working there or not?

Comment: my purpose is that one target has dual configuration at runtime. So my ios app could received notification for both firebase project.It's mean that ios app received notification from A project and B project.

Comment: "Can you create a sample application without any other code in it except the configuration and see if it's working there or not?" Have you done this part?

Comment: // Load a named file.
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyGoogleService", ofType: "plist")
guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
  else { assert(false, "Couldn't load config file") }
FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)                                                               ----------------------------------------------------

Comment: @HunterChen It still doesn't answer the question. Have you created a new iOS application just to test this functionality? Check this for reference - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i found the same question, https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/154#issuecomment-323999447